# Excel: Get Row Number from Another Cell to Calculate Average

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column of numbers. The number of rows for this column is always changing, sometimes it's 100 rows, sometimes it's 10 rows of numbers. On a second sheet, I am taking the average of this column of numbers. However, I am having to constantly update the range. Since I am using this range for multiple formulas (not just the average), I'm having to update the range in multiple areas.

I'd like to just reference a cell on that sheet, which I'll call max rows so that I simply need to update that cell, not every spot that uses the range. The range always starts on A2, but it could end on A40, A50, A100.

What formula do I use to get the end of the range so I only need to change a single cell?

Here's what I'm currently using:

```
=F9/10/(AVERAGE(SheetOne!A2:A19)/10)*0.2
```

So instead of always changing that 19, to however many rows I'll have next time, I want to reference a cell (say H2) that has the number of rows. Tricky thing is that I still need to tell it column A from SheetOne. I read something about INDEX and INDIRECT but not sure how to implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for something like:

```
SheetOne!A2:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(SheetOne!A:A))
```

Rather use `INDEX` to return the rownumber than `INDIRECT` as that would be volatile.

Comment: I believe `index` volatility is related to the version of excel... if you're using 2013 and beyond, you should be fine, otherwise `indirect`/`index` will both be volatile in 2010 and before versions

Comment: @Cyril, it is true it was volatile at some point in time, however it became non (or rather semi-) volatile in [Excel 97](http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsi.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the correction on the timing for that... thought it was much more recent

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having to use another cell you can just use the column in the average formula without specifying the row numbers.

This will work if A1 is a header with a string (not a number)

=F9/10/(AVERAGE(SheetOne!A:A)/10)*0.2